# QPixmap Object Quality Lost

Tags: c++, qt, qpixmap, qbytearray

I have a QChart on a QChartView object on my Qt App and I am trying to use that chart in a pdf which is generated by the app. The problem is after I generated html string into pdf the quality of my QChart lost a lot. Is there any way to improve the quality of .jpeg or generating it another way. I saw setTransformationMode method on QGraphicsPixmapItem object but I couldn't find any similar methods for QPixmap Object. Here is the sample of my code:

```
    QPixmap pixmap = chartView->grab();
    QPixmap outpixmap;
    QByteArray byteArray;
    QBuffer buffer(&byteArray);
    buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

    pixmap.save(&buffer,"JPG");

    QSize size(100,100);
    outpixmap.scaled(size,Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
    outpixmap.save("jpegName","JPG");

    QString html;

    html.append("<img src="+"jpegName"+"width='800', height='400'>");
```

Comment: JPEG is a lossy format. You might want to use PNG instead, for example.

Comment: You scaled your pixmap to 100x100 and then you want to insert it as 800x400. This explains why the image quality is bad. I'm pretty sure if you scaled it to 800x400 (the desired output resolution), it would be way better.

Comment: @Fareanor I changed QSize into desired output but quality of image didn't change.